# Flutter Navigator.pop() keeps the Dialog Box partially visible with black shadow background

Tags: flutter, navigation, dialog, bloc

sorry for the long explaination but I think I have to be very clear about the topic.

I have been running in this issue for last couple of weeks. I am using flutter_bloc package.

I have a simple Search page(ProposalSearchPage) with searchbox and listview. Listview gets build based on the search keyword which dispatches KeywordsearchEvent. on Clicking the setting icon it opens of ProposalSearchSetting page which is a dialog box page.

Based on this structure I have two events used in the bloc. One for the keyword search and another for the Advance filter search.

In  advance searching page after applying filters. Inside a button there I dispatched FilterSearchEvent and have used Navigation.pop(context) to return to ProposalSearchPage. 
Based on the state change The listview renders for both the searches, but for the Adavance filter search, the ProposalSearchSetting dialog box is partially visible. The filter button in there are clickable. It dismiss when I click backarrow button.

I don't know why Navigator.pop is adding page to stack instead of popping the stack.

```
  #PROPOSALSEARCH PAGE

class ProposalSearchPage extends StatefulWidget {
 final UserProfileBloc userProfileBloc;
 final MenuBloc menuBloc;
final String authToken;

  ProposalSearchPage({this.userProfileBloc, this.menuBloc, this.authToken})
  : assert(menuBloc != null),
    assert(userProfileBloc != null);

 @override
_ProposalSearchPageState createState() => _ProposalSearchPageState();
}

class _ProposalSearchPageState extends State<ProposalSearchPage> {
 UserProfileBloc get _userProfileBloc => widget.userProfileBloc;
 List filteredProposal = [];

String get _authToken => widget.authToken;

 MenuBloc get _menuBloc => widget.menuBloc;
ProposalSearchBloc _proposalSearchBloc;
String searchedKeyword = "";
int searchProposalPage = 1;

@override
void initState() {
_proposalSearchBloc =
    ProposalSearchBloc(proposalRepository: ProposalListingRepo());
_menuBloc.dispatch(MenuResponseFetchedEvent());
 super.initState();
}

@override
 void dispose() {
_proposalSearchBloc.dispose();
super.dispose();
  }

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Color(0xff2b57ff),
    leading: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.chevron_left),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      },
    ),
    actions: <Widget>[
      IconButton(
          icon: new Icon(CupertinoIcons.gear_big),
          onPressed: () {
          /*  Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => ProposalSearchSetting(
                    proposalSearchBloc: _proposalSearchBloc,
                    menuBloc: _menuBloc,
                    userProfileBloc: _userProfileBloc,
                    context: context),
                fullscreenDialog: true,
              ),
            );*/

              showDialog<FilterProposalPost>(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context) {
                    return ProposalSearchSetting(
                        proposalSearchBloc: _proposalSearchBloc,
                        menuBloc: _menuBloc,
                        userProfileBloc: _userProfileBloc,
                        context: context);
                  });
          }),
    ],
    title: Center(
      child: Container(
        width: 250.0,
        height: 35.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.black12,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(7.0))),
        child: CupertinoTextField(
          placeholder: 'search here.',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          onSubmitted: (keyword) {
            print(keyword);
            searchedKeyword = keyword;
            FilterProposalPost filterProposalPost =
                _buildSearchQueryParameter(keyword);
            // print(query);
            _proposalSearchBloc.proposalFilterPostParam(filterProposalPost);
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  body: SearchListing(_proposalSearchBloc, _authToken),
);
}

  FilterProposalPost _buildSearchQueryParameter(String keyword) {
  return FilterProposalPost(
  ........
   );
  }


  }


   }

 class SearchListing extends StatelessWidget {
 final ProposalSearchBloc _proposalSearchBloc;
 final String _authToken;

 SearchListing(this._proposalSearchBloc, this._authToken);

 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return BlocBuilder(
  bloc: _proposalSearchBloc,
  // ignore: missing_return
  builder: (context, state) {
    if (state is ProposalSearchFetchingState) {
      return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
            valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Color(0xff2b57ff))),
      );
    } else if (state is ProposalSearchFetchedState) {
      final filteredProposal = state.filteredProposal;
      print(filteredProposal.length.toString);
      return _buildSearchProposalList(filteredProposal);
    }
  },
);
}

 Widget _buildSearchProposalList(List searchedProposals) {
return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: searchedProposals.length + 1,
    itemBuilder: (context, position) {
      return position >= searchedProposals.length
          ? _buildLoaderListItem()
          : ProposalCardFactory(
              proposal: searchedProposals[position],
              authToken: _authToken,
            );
    });
}

Widget _buildLoaderListItem() {
return Center(
    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
        valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Color(0xff2b57ff))));
 }
   }






#ProposalSearchSettingPage

class ProposalSearchSetting extends StatefulWidget {
final UserProfileBloc userProfileBloc;
final ProposalSearchBloc proposalSearchBloc;
final MenuBloc menuBloc;
final BuildContext context;

final Function() notifyParent;

 ProposalSearchSetting({this.notifyParent,
  this.proposalSearchBloc,
  this.userProfileBloc,
  this.menuBloc,
  this.context});

   @override
  _ProposalSearchSettingState createState() => 
  _ProposalSearchSettingState();
   }

  class _ProposalSearchSettingState extends State<ProposalSearchSetting>
  with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  UserProfileBloc get _userProfileBloc => widget.userProfileBloc;

   ProposalSearchBloc get _proposalSearchBloc => widget.proposalSearchBloc;
   List<String> selectedOptions = [];
  String resultBy;

List<String> industries;
List<String> stages;
 List<String> locations;
List<String> languages;
List<String> countries;
List<String> regionsValue = [];

 MenuBloc get _menuBloc => widget.menuBloc;
 Animation<double> animation;
 AnimationController controller;
 double startingPoint;

 @override
 void initState() {
 super.initState();
}

@override
void dispose() {
_userProfileBloc.dispose();
 _proposalSearchBloc.dispose();
 super.dispose();
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 //double startingPoint = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
 return MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
      buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
          minWidth: 200.0,
          height: 40.0,
          buttonColor: Color(0xff2b57ff),
          textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary)),
  home: Scaffold(
    body: BlocBuilder(
      bloc: _menuBloc,
      // ignore: missing_return
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is MenuResponseFetchedState) {
          MenuListData _menuListData = state.menuListData;
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100.0),
            child: Center(
              child: Container(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        resultBy = await showDialog(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (context) {
                              return ResultBySearchDialog(
                                  userProfileBloc: _userProfileBloc,
                                  menuListData: _menuListData,
                                  title: 'Result By:',
                                  options: _menuListData.displayBy.values
                                      .toList());
                            });
                      },
                      color: Color(0xff2b57ff),
                      child: Text(
                        'RESULT BY',
                        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MyRaidPro'),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        countries = await showDialog(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (context) {
                              return CountrySearchDialog(
                                  userProfileBloc: _userProfileBloc,
                                  menuListData: _menuListData,
                                  title: 'Select Countries',
                                  selectedOptions: selectedOptions,
                                  onSelectedOptionListChanged: (options) {
                                    selectedOptions = options;
                                    print(selectedOptions);
                                  });
                            });
                      },
                      color: Color(0xff2b57ff),
                      child: Text(
                        'COUNTRY',
                        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MyRaidPro'),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        industries = await showDialog(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (context) {
                              return IndustrySearchDialog(
                                  menuListData: _menuListData,
                                  title: 'Select Industries',
                                  options: _menuListData.industries.values
                                      .toList(),
                                  selectedOptions: selectedOptions,
                                  onSelectedOptionListChanged: (options) {
                                    selectedOptions = options;
                                    print(selectedOptions);
                                  });
                            });
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        'INDUSTRIES',
                        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MyRaidPro'),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        stages = await showDialog(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (context) {
                              return StageSearchDialog(
                                context: context,
                                  menuListData: _menuListData,
                                  title: 'Select Stages',
                                  options:
                                  _menuListData.stages.values.toList(),
                                  selectedOptions: selectedOptions,
                                  onSelectedOptionListChanged: (options) {
                                    selectedOptions = options;
                                    print(selectedOptions);
                                  });
                            });
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        'STAGES',
                        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MyRaidPro'),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        languages = await showDialog(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (context) {
                              return LanguageSearchDialog(
                                  menuListData: _menuListData,
                                  title: 'Select Languages',
                                  options: _menuListData.languages.values
                                      .toList(),
                                  selectedOptions: selectedOptions,
                                  onSelectedOptionListChanged: (options) {
                                    selectedOptions = options;
                                    print(selectedOptions);
                                  });
                            });
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        'LANGUAGES',
                        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MyRaidPro'),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        locations = await showDialog(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (context) {
                              return LocationSearchDialog(
                                  menuListData: _menuListData,
                                  title: 'Select Locations',
                                  options: _menuListData.locations.values
                                      .toList(),
                                  selectedOptions: selectedOptions,
                                  onSelectedOptionListChanged: (options) {
                                    selectedOptions = options;
                                    print(selectedOptions);
                                  });
                            });
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        'LOCATIONS',
                        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MyRaidPro'),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 40,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ButtonTheme(
                          textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary,
                          minWidth: 60,
                          child: RaisedButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.of(this.widget.context).pop();
                            },
                            color: Color(0xff2b57ff),
                            child: Text(
                              'Cancel',
                              style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MyRaidPro'),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        ButtonTheme(
                          textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary,
                          minWidth: 60,
                          child: RaisedButton(
                            onPressed: () {


_proposalSearchBloc.dispatch(ProposalFilterFetchEvent(advanceFilter: 
 FilterProposalPost(......)));
                              Navigator.pop(context);

                              print(("value from dialog" +
                                  industries.toString()));

                              print(("value from dialog" +
                                  stages.toString()));

                              print(("value from dialog" +
                                  locations.toString()));

                              print(("value from dialog" +
                                  languages.toString()));
                            },
                            color: Color(0xff2b57ff),
                            child: Text(
                              'Apply',
                              style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MyRaidPro'),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

}

```
#BLOC



class ProposalSearchBloc
extends Bloc<ProposalSearchEvent, ProposalSearchState> {
  final ProposalListingRepo proposalRepository;
List keywordSearchedProposalList = List();
List filteredProposalList = List();

ProposalSearchBloc({this.proposalRepository});

 void proposalFilterPostParam(FilterProposalPost filterProposalPost) {
 dispatch(ProposalSearchFetchEvent(filterProposalPost: filterProposalPost));
 }



  @override
  ProposalSearchState get initialState => ProposalSearchFetchingState();

 @override
 Stream<ProposalSearchState> mapEventToState(event) async* {
try {
  var filteredProposal;
  print("proposal search even fired first time");
  if (event is ProposalSearchFetchEvent) {
    filteredProposal =
        await proposalRepository.filterProposal(event.filterProposalPost);
  } else if (event is ProposalFilterFetchEvent) {
    print("filter event");

    filteredProposal =
        await proposalRepository.filterProposal(event.advanceFilter);
    filteredProposalList.addAll(filteredProposal);
    yield ProposalSearchFetchedState(filteredProposal: filteredProposal);
  }
 } catch (_) {
  //print(error.toString());
  yield ProposalSearchErrorState();
 }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to solve the problem. I just forgot to use try catch blok in my bloc. This solves most of the problems of reloading the previous page after changing configuration from another page (DialogBox Box probably). I just had to make few changes in the Bloc code as:

```
 @override
  Stream<ProposalSearchState> mapEventToState(event) async* {
    yield ProposalSearchFetchingState();
  if (event is ProposalSearchFetchEvent) {
   try {
    print("proposal search");
    filteredProposal =
        await proposalRepository.filterProposal(event.filterProposalPost);

    yield ProposalSearchFetchedState(
        searchedProposal: filteredProposal);
  } catch (error) {
    print(error);
  }

  if (event is ProposalFilterFetchEvent) {
    try {
      print("proposal filtered");
      filteredProposal =
          await proposalRepository.filterProposal(event.filterProposalPost);

      yield ProposalFilteredFetchedState(
          filteredProposal: filteredProposal);
    } catch (error) {
      print(error.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

}